# How to get Photo Booth Flash Effect like on MacBook Pro

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, flash, camera

I have a white flash that appears to alert the user that a picture was taken but the white flash doesn't add light to my photos. My photos are still dark no matter what I have done. I have changed the duration of the flash and moved 
`[[self captureManager] captureStillImage];` 
to take pictures after the flash and still no luck.  I have looked at the photo booth app on my `Macbook` and it seems that the flash comes just a little bit before the image is captured and it provides light to the photos in the dark. I want to replicate this. Can anyone help me?

```
- (IBAction)captureStillImage2:(id)sender
{
// Capture a still image
[[self stillButton] setEnabled:NO];


// Flash the screen white and fade it out to give UI feedback that a still image was taken
UIView *flashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self videoPreviewView] frame]];
[flashView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[[self view] window] addSubview:flashView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^{
                     [[self captureManager] captureStillImage];
                     [flashView setAlpha:0.f];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     [flashView removeFromSuperview];
                     [flashView release];
                 }
 ];
}
```

Comment: What is displayed on the screen has nothing to do with what the camera is capturing.

Comment: Do you know any solutions that might solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the brightness using something like `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];` for iOS5+ .

Keep in mind though, that the effect on a small display like an iphone won't be able to match the effect of a full sized macbook pro (it's all about **brightness** and **backlit area**).

Comment: Thanks for replying! I already have a UISlider that controls the devices brightness and I have it fully turned up when I am taking test photos, but they are still coming out dark in one of my views. I have two different views that users can use and one provides a backlit area and works very good, but I want my second view, which is the fullscreen mode, to provide some sense of flash like the way the app "Camera+" does. Do you know how I can go about this?

Comment: I don't have camera+ installed, but if you want to use your display as a small light source for photos with your front facing camera, the only thing you can do to maximize the effect is to present a purely white view on the entire screen and with maximum brightness.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean. If you could, check out my app in the App Store & so maybe you can get a better sense of what I am talking about. It's called Front-Flash.

Comment: I looked it up and that's what I meant. I'm sorry, but I think the only way you'd be able to add more light is to choose a bigger frame (if videoPreviewView doesn't already include the whole screen)